# Array destructuring incorrectly infers the type of created array

Tags: typescript

If we have an object typed as a union of two arrays of different types:

```
const original = [] as string[] | number[];
```

After the destructuring assignment the type changes to array of union of said types:

```
const copy = [...original]; // (string | number)[];
```

Which widened the type for no reason.

And what's worse, `Array.from` doesn't even work:

```
const copyFrom = Array.from(original);
// Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

But it does with explicit typing:

```
const copyExplicit = Array.from<string | number>(arr);
```

Typescript version is 3.7.3

Comment: The type isn't incorrect, just weaker than is possible to prove. Generally, `tsc` doesn't try to prove every provable property of your code. In this case, the rule being applied is presumably that `[...arr]` is an array whose component type is whatever type a component of `arr` could be; that's a weaker rule than could be written for the special case of `[...arr]`, but also a more general rule which works for examples like `[elem1, elem2, ...arr1, ...arr2]`.

Comment: As a workaround, you can use a type assertion; it may be more convenient to put the assertion in a generic function like `function copyArray<T extends any[]>(arr: T): T { return [...arr] as T; }`. Then `const copyFrom = copyArray(original);` infers the stricter type.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy array without loosing type, just use slice

```
const copy = original.slice();
```

[demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=5&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBOBLA5osBDANjAvDA2gLozoQwAU0SYyRMAPjGAK4C2ARgKbxECUA3AChBoSLFAAHAJ644SVBkwA6CJkTBO5ATAD0OmFTS1ijFh25EhgoA)

Comment: Those are not the types in question. `string[] | number[]` is narrower than `(string | number)[]`.

Comment: you are right, that's the point, Array.from expects iterable of any union type, but you passing many union type of iterable

Comment: But I don't want to pass an array of union, I want to create a new array typed as union of array types... So I want to create a `string[] | number[]` from `string[] | number[]`, not `(string | number)[]`

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly The problem is how to copy an array of arbitrary type without weakening the type of the new array. Your answer proposes weakening the type of the original array, which means it doesn't work for an arbitrary type.